# Git Error: stash or commit

Tags: git, github

I'm fairly new to Git and I'm struggling with an error.

I have a local copy of the code that is in prod, and made some changes (after a `git pull`). After making the local changes, I did:

```
git add .
git commit -m
git push
```

Then I logged into the prod server, and ran `git pull`.
I got the following error:

```
-> origin/master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
```

I'm not sure how it would affect my code if I stash the changes or made a commit. What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error means that you have changes to your files on the prod server that are going to be clobbered by the `git pull` command that you are trying to run.  Git decides that this is probably not what you want to do.

You could run `git status` to see what you have that isn't checked in/tracked on the prod server to see what you want to do with those changes.  Then you have three options:

1. `git reset`: those changes I don't need, get rid of them by resetting to the previous commit and then do the pull.
2. `git commit` (adding relevant files first): those changes need to be in version control, check them in please.  And then pull the latest changes over the top of those changes.
3. `git stash`: those changes are a work in progress and I don't want to lose them, but I don't want to check them in yet either.  You can retrieve them later.

Comment: Awesome explanation for noobs like me

Comment: Is it possible to reset one particular file?